# get the size of a transformed div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, height

I have a div that can have either height 22 or 44 px. I use panzoom to pan and zoom and apply a transformation mask. What I would need is to get the height value of the div WITHOUT the transformation.

I tried .height(), .css("height") but both return the transformed value and not the original (that i can see if i do analyze the code using the browser)

Is there a way to get this value without knowing the transformation that has been applied?

Comment: When the div is transformed, add a class `transformed`. Then use `$('div').not('.transformed').outerHeight();`. I used `.outerHeight` instead of `height` because it takes into consideration margin and padding. If you don't want to take into account margin and padding, use `.height()`.

Comment: To answer your question. You need to know the transformation has been applied to get the value. You are trying to get a value from a single element that can exist in 2 states(transformed, and not). You need to know which state in order to get the proper value.